# Applying ssl only to admin routes of site

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, https

I have a website made in PHP Laravel 5.1 with the PingPong admin package for the administration CMS of this very site.

The routes are like:

> mywebsite » *for the public website*
>
> mywebsite/admin » *for the admin CMS*

My client wants to add a SSL protocol only in the mywebsite/admin route.
Is it possible to do that?
If it is, do I need to add some extra lines of code for that?

Comment: follow this discussion https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/implementing-https-for-laravel-5

Comment: "My client wants to add a SSL protocol only in the mywebsite/admin route" — Don't. It is a pointless waste of resources (and risk of introducing bugs) to try to determine if something doesn't need to be secure and turn of SSL for it. Just use SSL everywhere. It's easier, it's better for users, and it's better food for search engines.

Comment: So, there is no drawback of use SSL in the entire site, right? I will communicate that to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a middleware that redirects when the URL is not secure (via HTTPS). And then enable that middleware on the routes that you want to enforce SSL:

```
<?php // app/Http/Middleware/Secure.php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Secure
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$request->isSecure()) {
            return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Add the middleware in your `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'secure' => \App\Http\Middleware\Secure::class
];
```

And enable the middleware on the admin routes, for example using a route group:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'secure', 'prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    // here your routes (without 'admin/' prefix)
});
```

Now when, someone goes to the admin URL via normal HTTP, he will be redirected to the HTTPS version of that route.

Of course, you need to setup a certificate in a proper way such that the site can be accessed by both HTTP and HTTPS.